# Vector Class Constructor Arguments

Tags: python

I need to write a class constructor that has these criteria:

The constructor should take a single argument. If this argument is either an int or a long or an instance of a class derived from one of these, then consider this argument to be the length of the Vector. In this case, construct a Vector of the specified length with each element is initialized to 0.0. If the length is negative, raise a `ValueError` with an appropriate message. If the argument is not considered to be the length, then if the argument is a sequence (such as a `list`), then initialize with a vector with the length and values of the given sequence. If the argument is not used as the length of the vector, and if it is not a sequence, then raise a `TypeError` with an appropriate message.

I'm not sure how to write the appropriate errors, I'm supposed to use this class for errors:

```
class Failure(Exception):
    """Failure exception"""
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value=value
    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self.value)
```

At the interactive console:

```
>>> Vector(3)
Vector([0.0, 0.0, 0.0])
>>> Vector(3L)
Vector([0.0, 0.0, 0.0])
>>> Vector([4.5, "foo", 0])
Vector([4.5, 'foo', 0])
>>> Vector(0)
Vector([])
>>> Vector(-4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
  File "vector.py", line 14, in __init__
    raise ValueError("Vector length cannot be negative")
ValueError: Vector length cannot be negative
```

Here is my code. I just need to add the errors, one in the `if` statement for when it's an `int` or a `long` that is a value error, and one in the `else` statement for `TypeError`:

```
def is_sequence(obj):
    try:
        len(obj)
        obj[0:0]
        return True
    except TypeError:
        return False

class Vector:
    l=[]

    def __init__(self,object):
        if(isinstance(object,long) |isinstance(object,int)):
            x=int(object)
            if(x<0):

            else:
                for i in range(0,x):
                    l.append(0.0)

        elif(is_sequence(object)):
            l.append(object)

        else:
```

I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: SO isn't "code write" service, what code have you tried so far ? what particular problem do you have ?

Comment: You are supposed to show us some code _you_ have written, then we help you fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Vector:

    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.v = []
        if(isinstance(obj, (int, long)): # For Python3 use isinstance(obj, int)
            if(x < 0):
                # raise error
            else:
                self.v += [0.0] * x

        else:
            self.v += obj  # raises a type error is obj is not a sequence
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
if type(value) == <type 'list'> :  

if type(value) == <type 'int'> :
```

and so on by using multiple conditional statements.

Comment: That is not the correct syntax for what you are trying to do.

Comment: "either an int or a long or an instance of a class derived from one of these"